# Distinguish dataclass classes from dataclass instances in python type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, duck-typing

Following the recommendations in [type hint for an instance of a non specific dataclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668000/type-hint-for-an-instance-of-a-non-specific-dataclass), I was able to define a `Protocol` to identify classes decorated with `@dataclass`, i.e.

```
class DataclassProtocol(Protocol):
    __dataclass_fields__: Dict
```

This works well, but I now need to distinguish between a (non-specific) dataclass *class* and a (non-specific) dataclass *instance*. The protocol above matches both so it can't be used to discriminate.

Based on the source code in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/dataclasses.py, it seems that one possible discriminator is that dataclasses classes inherit from `type`, while dataclasses instances do not.

Can this be used to derive type hints to discriminate correctly dataclass classes from dataclass instances? Or is there another way?

Comment: Are you sure that the protocol you define matches both? [Playground where it doesn't hold true](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a034c938c6d0f8191d4c6bb99b3f3624)

Comment: *all* classes inherit from `type`, so the facts need to be set straight here

Comment: @SUTerliakov you are 100% right, I was testing the protocol by decorating it with `@runtime_checkable` and then using `isinstance`, both were matching. But in `mypy` instead, the dataclass class doesn't match. This means that there is a way! I ended up renaming the protocol to `DataclassInstanceProtocol` and using it for instances, while for dataclass classes I simply use `Type[DataclassInstanceProtocol]`. Works perfectly, here the gist: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=d73e1af7992248a237e93d0e1c640368