# Where can I import "DataclassInstance" for mypy check?

Tags: python

I have been using custom-defined [DataclassProtocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240861/11501976) to annotate the arg of function which takes dataclass type. It was something like this:

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Type


class DataclassProtocol(Protocol):
    """Type annotation for dataclass type object."""

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240861/11501976
    __dataclass_fields__: Dict


def f(dcls: Type[DataclassProtocol]):
    return dataclasses.fields(dcls)
```

But recent mypy check fails with message:
`error: Argument 1 to "fields" has incompatible type "type[DataclassProtocol]"; expected "DataclassInstance | type[DataclassInstance]"  [arg-type]`

It seems I should now annotate with this `DataclassInstance`, but I can't find out from where I can import this. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may import it from `_typeshed`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed import DataclassInstance
```

Note that types from `_typeshed` do not exist at runtime. You may read more about them here:

- [`_typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/main/stdlib/_typeshed)
- [`_typeshed.DataclassInstance`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/53422f8918debdaf60e1605d0e2e3ce77a810afd/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L313-L314)

Comment: Didn't know they are not in runtime. Thanks!

Comment: This does help with some things, but doesn't seem to get mypy to report an issue if a function expects a DataClassInstance, but is passed a non-dataclass instead.